# Wordpress: default option page values not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, function, admin

I'm not entirely sure way but the default values for a custom form aren't displaying. Any ideas?

Is it something to do with locating templates?

```
$blav_options_address = array(
    'street' => 'Street Address',
    'county' => 'County Address',
    'postcode' => 'Postcode',
);

function blavou_setup_address() {
    global $blav_options_address;
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['updated'] ) )
        $_REQUEST['updated'] = false;
    ?>
    <?php if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
        echo "<div class='updated'><p>Settings Saved. <a href='?page=blav-setup-social'>Continue Setup</a>.</p></div>";
    } ?>
    <?php locate_template( 'admin/templates/blav-setup-address.php', TRUE, TRUE ); ?>
    <?php
}


<div id="blav-wrapper">
<div class="blav-nav-wrapper">
    <h5 class="standard-title">Photographers Address</h5>
    <form method="post" action="options.php" class="standard-form">
    <?php $settings = get_option( 'blav_options_address', $blav_options_address ); ?>
    <?php settings_fields( 'blav_theme_options_address' );?>
        <input type="text" name="blav_options_address[street]" value="<?php esc_attr_e($settings['street']); ?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="blav_options_address[county]" value="<?php esc_attr_e($settings['county']); ?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="blav_options_address[postcode]" value="<?php esc_attr_e($settings['postcode']); ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
    </form>
</div><!--end blav nav wrapper-->
</div><!--end blav-wrapper-->
```

Comment: If you display the contents of $settings, what do you get?

Comment: Apologies made a mistake of what I had copied and pasted. The array at the top is meant to display in the value where specified. If I display the settings front end without filling in it shows nothing. If complete the form it displays as completed @bobdye

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that get_option() is not doing what you expect. When you execute:

```
$settings = get_option( 'blav_options_address', $blav_options_address );
```

then the only time that the default (`$blav_options_address`) will be used is if the option `blav_options_address` is not found. If that option is in the database, then the returned value will be used regardless of whether it is of the correct form or not, e.g.even if it is not an array. If it is not an array with the correct keys, then of course nothing will be displayed for the input values.

Comment: But if the option isnt in the database it should work? I gave it a try on a different databased with no joys :/